# Difference quotient of $f(x)= 2-6x+4x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find $f(a), f(a + h)$, and the difference quotient

$$\frac {f(a + h) − f(a)}{h},$$

where $h\neq 0$ and $f(x) = 2-6x+4x^2$.

My work:

$$f(a) = 2-6a+4a^2,\ \ f(a+h) = 2-6(a+h)+4(a+h)^2.$$

I need help on the last one:

$$\frac {f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.$$

My work:

\begin{split} \frac {f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} &= \frac {(a+h)-(a)}{h}\\
&= \frac {2-6a-6h+4a^2+8ah+8h^2-2+6a-4a^2}{h}\\
&=\frac {-6h+8ah+8h^2}{h}\\
&= {-6+8a+8h}
\end{split}

UPDATE: It looks like I accidentally squared the numerator. So instead it would be $\frac{6+8a+8h}{h}$. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: On the line right under "My work:", why do you put $(a+h)^2-(a)^2$ in the numerator instead of $f(a+h)-f(a)$?

Comment: Not sure why I squared it. I re-solved it and got -6+8a+8h. Is this correct? I'll edit "my work", it may take a few minutes.

Comment: I typed up my answer before your edits. It seems the only thing we disagree on is the $8h^2$ term.

Comment: I foiled $4(a+h)^2$ wrong,you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$, but you seem to have computed something else not involving $f$. Try this, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\frac{(2-6(a+h)+4(a+h)^2)-(2-6a+4a^2)}{h} \\
=\frac{2-6a-6h+4a^2+8ah+4h^2-2+6a-4a^2}{h} \\
=\frac{-6h+8ah+4h^2}{h} \\
=-6+8a+4h
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!